# Use socat as https to http proxy

Tags: ssl, socat

Based on https://superuser.com/questions/1583159/secure-connection-failed-to-old-printer-with-https I was thinking:

Can `socat` (or similar) be used to connect to the printer with an old https version and set up a local http port that I can point the browser to?

Something like:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:8000 ssl:myprinter:443
```

When I now point my browser to localhost:8000 `socat` says:

```
2020/09/06 11:31:50 socat[1903771] E SSL_connect(): error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
```

This sounds as if `socat` cannot speak the SSL dialect that my printer does.

Is there something else I can do?

Comment: And does `openssl s_client -connect myprinter:443` work?

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible that your socat (or the SSL library version it links against) do not support SSL2/SSL3 and that's the best the printer can do. In theory, you can set up a VM with a sufficiently rusty distro, say CentOS5, and build a *static* socat there, i.e. it will have all libraries baked in. You can then copy that socat binary and hopefully use it on a more modern machine. (`configure --help` for socat might have a switch to build statically.)